# c# how do I turn this data into a cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, cookies

I'm making a wrapper for a forum API, one function returns this, which is meant to provide enough information for you to set a cookie to log the user in with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>    
<ApiResponse>    
 <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>    
 <ErrorDescription/>    
 <ResultData recordcount="1">    
  <Record>  
   <Username>Gullanian</Username>    
   <UserID>4</UserID>    
   <CookieName>WWF9sLID</CookieName>    
   <CookieKey>UID</CookieKey>    
   <CookieData>Gullanian-CD45-ZCB-D72Z-AAC6</CookieData>    
   <CookiePath>/scirranew/forum/</CookiePath>
   <ForumPath>http://127.0.0.1/scirranew/Forum/</ForumPath> 
  </Record>    
 </ResultData>    
</ApiResponse>
```

I've got as far as this:

```
public class WebWizCookie
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string CookieName { get; set; }
    public string CookieKey { get; set; }
    public string CookieData { get; set; }
    public string CookiePath { get; set; }
    public string ForumPath { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads this cookie so user is logged in with this cookie data.
    /// </summary>
    public void LoadCookie(double MinutesExpiry)
    {
        HttpCookie Cookie = new HttpCookie(this.CookieName);
        Cookie[this.CookieKey] = this.CookieData;
        Cookie.Domain = this.CookiePath;
        Cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(MinutesExpiry);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(Cookie);
    }
```

It's returning all the values fine, but I'm not being logged into the site when I call this function.  Does anyone know if I'm doing anything wrong here?  Forgetting to set something, or setting it incorrectly?

### Edit, printing out values

After setting the cookie, if I print out the values:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Cookie[" + this.CookieKey + "] = " + this.CookieData + "<br />");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Cookie.Domain = " + ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MasterDomainRoot"] + "<br />");
```

I get:

```
Cookie[UID] = Gullanian2-4B9B-9D5-27E2-A413
Cookie.Domain = http://localhost/ScirraNew
UID
```

And in google chrome the developer tools says there is a cookie:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Cookie.Domain` is wrong. See [`HttpCookie.Domain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.domain.aspx) on MSDN - it should merely contain the domain (e.g. "localhost") not the full path ("http://localhost/ScirraNew"). There is a `Path` property if you want to restrict a cookie to only certain parts of your site, but that is a rarely-used feature (I've never come across a reason to do it).

By the way, you don't need to set the `Domain` property - by default, cookies are shared by all pages that are in the same domain. You really only need to set it if you have to share cookies between different subdomains (e.g. www.mysite.com and secure.mysite.com, you'd need to set `Domain` to "mysite.com")

Answer (score 1):

First step is to determine if the cookie is being properly created. Have you checked? (You can use the [web developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) for Firefox to do this).

Comment: Hi, thanks, I've uploaded chrome developer screenshot of cookie, and data being saved too cookie.  The value looks wrong?  And the domain as well?

Comment: I've removed the add this component, and it appears the cookie I'm trying to set isn't setting at all.  So my problem is the cookie isn't being saved.  Is the code to save it wrong?